# Is there a way to reroute files downloaded from a specific domain to a new folder?

Tags: finder, automator, data-transfer, macos

This seems like a really simple issue and perhaps I'm overthinking it.

My specific use case for this is:

- I've downloaded a pdf/image/etc. from a website
- I'd like to take that file and move it from my default downloads folder to another folder (This would be a start. In the future, I'd like to do different variations of this with rules based on filetype, size, etc.).

I've looked up a number of options that don't quite get me where I want. I've read that applications like Automator, fswatch, etc. are good tools for this. I'm unsure of their specific implementation and was hoping for some insight and/or help in putting something together.

I currently use Firefox and they used to have an extension that would reroute files based on whatever given rules. This is not the case after the release of Quantum.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it myself, but I've heard good things about [Hazel](https://www.noodlesoft.com). From their website:

> Hazel watches whatever folders you tell it to, automatically organizing your files according to the rules you create. Have Hazel move files around based on name, date, type, what site it came from and much more.